# Intercalate function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and I wanted to do a function where it receives two numbers and it intercalates between positive and negative.
Thanks for your help.
example:

```
intercalarNum 5 2 = [2,-2,2,-2,2]
```

Tried to do it many ways but ghci says it has a error everytime so I dont know what do do anymore

```
intercalarNum :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a -> [a]
intercalarNum 0 y = []
intercalarNum x y = y : intercalarnumAux  (intercalarNum (x-1) y)
intercalarnumAux :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a 
intercalarnumAux x | x < 0 = -x 
                   | x > 0 = -x 
                   | x == 0 = 0
```

Comment: I would say *alternate* here, not intercalate. (`Data.List.intercalate` is the function that joins a list of strings into a single string, with a given delimiter, e.g. `intercalate "-" ["a", "b"] == "a-b"`.)

Comment: What error do you get? (`intercalarnumAux` appears unnecessary; you can simply use `(negate y)` as the second argument to `intercalarNum`.)

Comment: One could use manual recursion here. Like this: `alternate n k = if (n <= 0) then [] else k : (alternate (n-1) (negate k))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start form this part:

```
intercalarnumAux :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a 
intercalarnumAux x | x < 0 = -x 
                   | x > 0 = -x 
                   | x == 0 = 0
```

Now, that very last `0` can also be written as `-0`, and since `x==0`, that can also be written as `-x`. If we choose to do that, we get

```
intercalarnumAux :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a 
intercalarnumAux x | x < 0  = -x 
                   | x > 0  = -x 
                   | x == 0 = -x
```

hence we discover that the result is `-x` in all cases! We could simply write

```
intercalarnumAux :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a 
intercalarnumAux x = -x
```

or even

```
intercalarnumAux :: (Num a) => a -> a 
intercalarnumAux x = -x
```

We could also not define this function at all, and simply use uniry minus (aka negation) `- ....` as needed.

Now, let's examine the main routine:

```
intercalarNum :: (Num a , Ord a ) => a -> a -> [a]
intercalarNum 0 y = []
intercalarNum x y = y : intercalarnumAux  (intercalarNum (x-1) y)
```

This actually looks rather good. While it is still wrong as you discovered trying to compile it, it gets most things correct.

The base case where the first argument is `0` is correct.

The inductive case starts the output list as `y : ...`, which is correct.
It also decrements `x` in the recursive call, passing `x-1` which is correct.

Now, there is one last thing to fix. You are very close, so let me give you a hint. Right now you call `intercalarnumAux  (intercalarNum (x-1) y)` which means  `- (intercalarNum (x-1) y)` but you can't negate a *list* like that. Try to negate a number instead. Well, don't negate `x-1` since decrementing that is correct. Can you spot some other number to negate? Just remember to use parentheses as in `(- somethingToNegateHere)`, otherwise the minus sign could be interpreted as binary subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Given I understand it correctly, the first number is the amount of numbers you want to generate, and the second number is the value that each time is negated for the next number.

If that is the case, both numbers don't need to have the same type. Indeed, we can use an `Int` for the number of items, and a `Float` for the type of the items.

We can also make use of two helper functions here: [**`genericTake :: Integral i -> i -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericTake) to take the first *n* items, and [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate), which produces and endless list by each time applying the function to it.

In that case we can implement the function as:

```
import Data.List(genericTake)

intercalarNum :: (Integral i, Num a) => i -> a -> [a]
intercalarNum n x = genericTake n (iterate negate x)
```

or shorter:

```
import Data.List(genericTake)

intercalarNum :: (Integral i, Num a) => i -> a -> [a]
intercalarNum n = genericTake n . iterate negate
```

We here let `iterate negate` generate an endless list of `[2, -2, 2, -2, …]` and then we only take the first *n* items of that list.

Comment: I'd actually prefer something like `cycle [x, -x]` to `iterate negate`, just to avoid accidentally building a deeply-nested thunk of `negate` applications.